# Zig zag lines instead of straight line in linear modeling

Tags: r, linear-regression

Dataset: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WeVLvDmqPOdpkcXe5W66ymFIerdllDTG/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to fit a linear model on the above dataset using R.

Here is the code in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Salary_Data.csv")

s_data <- data.frame(scale(data)) 

# Split data into test and train data sets
set.seed(123)
sam <- sample(c(T, F), size = nrow(s_data), replace=T, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
train <- s_data[sam,]
test <- s_data[!sam,]

model_train = lm(YearsExperience~Salary, data=train);

pred <- predict.lm(object = model_train, newdata = test)
pred_train <- predict.lm(model_train, train)


# Trying to plot using ggplot on test dataset. 
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = test$YearsExperience, y = test$Salary),
             colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x = test$YearsExperience, y = predict.lm(model_train, test)),
            colour = 'blue') +
  ggtitle('Salary vs Experience (Test set)') +
  xlab('Years of experience') +
  ylab('Salary')
```

Output

[image: not a straight line]

My understanding is that the simple linear regression model predicts values based on a linear equation of the form `ax+b`. So `y` values in `geom_line()` must fit in a straight line, but in my case, they don't. Why is that happening? Thanks for reading!

Comment: `geom_line` just connects points for you. It does not fit a linear regression. If you want linear regression use `geom_smooth(..., method="lm")` See the `?geom_smooth` help page for more information.

Comment: Also if you were expecing a straigt line with your model, you have your `x` and `y` flipped. Your model `model_train = lm(YearsExperience~Salary, data=train)` is predicting years of experience based on salary. In that case, Salary shoud be on the x axis. Maybe you meant `model_train = lm(Salary~YearsExperience, data=train)``

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just have a problem flipping your `x` and `y` values. If you plot years of experience on the `x` axis, it looks like you are trying to use that to predict salary. But your model is backwards. So you can flip the model and get a straight line

```
model_train = lm(Salary~YearsExperience, data=train);

ggplot(data.frame(test, pred=predict(model_train, newdata = test))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = YearsExperience, y = Salary),
             colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x = YearsExperience, y = pred),
            colour = 'blue') +
  ggtitle('Salary vs Experience (Test set)') +
  xlab('Years of experience') +
  ylab('Salary')
```

[image]
Or you can flip the plot to get a straight line

```
model_train = lm(YearsExperience~Salary, data=train);

ggplot(data.frame(test, pred=predict(model_train, newdata = test))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Salary, y = YearsExperience),
             colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x = Salary, y = pred),
            colour = 'blue') +
  ggtitle('Salary vs Experience (Test set)')
```

[image]